# My .exe file was not able to access the model file

Tags: python

After converting my .py file to .exe my program was not able to access the caffemodel and prototxt.

When I run the .exe file this is the error I'm getting
[image]

This is my project file:

[image]

I've used pyinstaller to convert my Image_Colorizer.py to .exe

By using this command:

`pyinstaller --onefile -w Image_Colorizer.py`

After converting, when I click on .exe file. It was not able to access the caffemodel from the model folder.

Comment: you need to figure out how to tell pyinstaller that you have resource files it needs to include in the package

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That's what I want to know

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I've tried using --add-data while creating the .exe file, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html